# difference between installation testing and compatibility testing?

Tags: manual-testing

What is the difference between Installation Testing and Compatibility Testing in context of software Testing ?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. Have you googled the two concepts or searched existing questions? http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1425/installation-testing-is-part-of-functional-or-non-functional-testing is one question here that could help. There are many others. Perhaps you could update your question with more context - what you've looked for and why that information didn't help you.

Comment: Hi Selva, there are two key hallmarks of a great question missing here. The first is prior research effort: what steps have you taken to answer the question already? This lets answers know where to pick up where you left off. The second is the problem to be solved. Stack Exchange is about more than just answering questions, it's about solving problems. What problems involving Installation Testing and Compatibility Testing have you run into in which knowing their differences would help? Often times, half of solving the problem is asking the right questions.

Answer (score 1):

In general, **Installation Testing** checks for the ability to properly install the system-under-test, where **Compatibility Testing** checks that the system-under-test is compatible across several environments/platforms/browsers/etc.

These two terms are mostly unrelated.

For other terms, see: http://www.allthingsquality.com/p/testing-terms-glossary.html